# How can I get all information of a href from @Html.Raw in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem about getting a href from `@Html.Raw` in ASP.NET MVC.

NewsInformation contains this kind of information:

```
<p>News Information</p>
<p>.....</p>
....
<a href="Website Link Source">Link<a/>
```

Here is all news information in this code which is shown below.

```
<p>
@Html.Raw(@Model.NewsInformation)
</p>
```

What I just want to do is like this shown below.

```
<p>
@Html.Raw(@Model.NewsInformation)
<a href="Website Link Source">Link<a/>
</p>
```

How can I extract this `<a>` tag from `@Model.NewsInformation` ?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
@model ....

@{
   var link = new HtmlString(Model.NewsInformation);
}
    
....
....

<p> @link </p>
```

for a big chank of html you can use jquery for example

create div where you put your html

```
<div id="myHtml"> </div>
```

java script section of view

```
@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data =  '@Model.NewsInformation';
            var myHtml = $('<div />').html(data).text();
            $('#div').html(myHtml);
            //or you can try
            $('#myHtml).append(myHtml);
        });
</script>
}
```

Comment: I updated my post. NewsInformation cannot only have link but only some texts.

Comment: What do you mean by only some texts.?

Comment: Some texts + <a href> I show a sample information of NewsInformation  in my post as you can see.

Comment: @TonyBrand I updated my answer. Hope it will work

Comment: I'll try it. I hope your result can fix my issue.

Comment: I got an error in console part. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` as it is the issue here `var myHtml =<p>skadasdasldasmdmlas</p>;`

Comment: @TonyBrand I made some changes. You can try again and let me know.